# Draw a value rather than a cube - ARToolKit iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, artoolkit

I start by saying that I don't know OpenGL (I just followed some tutorials).
I'm working on a demo application that uses [ARToolKit](http://www.artoolworks.com/products/mobile/artoolkit-for-ios/) . Basically if the marker is detected I need to display some data (just a numerical value) that I receive from the web. I have already looked at the ARApp example and I'd like to see the numerical value on each(or just on top) surface of the cube, or even the value in 3D instead of the cube.
I found [this tutorial](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/draw_text/text.php)(ideal for my case) but it is in C++, uses a class that allow you to render strings in 3D. Does anyone knows a way to use it in iOS, or at least some input on what can i integrate/use to draw a value rather than a cube?

Libraries, links and any references are appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @JøhnNârrøw Unfortunately not.